# Unable to run R Functions on Azure after adding Site extension

Tags: r, azure, azure-functions

I am totally new to R so must be missing something simple I think.

I am trying to see how we can run R code as Azure functions. I followed [this](https://github.com/thdeltei/azure-function-r) example and to simplify I replaced the script.r file with

`print("Testing R")`

but when I run this function I see the following in the command line:

```
2017-09-01T14:07:52.388 Function started (Id=c031b7fc-1047-442e-8589-8cc6e7a96b48)
2017-09-01T14:07:54.407 Loading required package: httr
2017-09-01T14:07:54.611 Loading required package: jsonlite
2017-09-01T14:07:54.689 Loading required package: methods
2017-09-01T14:07:55.174 Loading required package: ggplot2
2017-09-01T14:07:57.624 Loading required package: twitteR
2017-09-01T14:07:58.943 Loading required package: rsvg
2017-09-01T14:07:59.366 Loading required package: rjson
2017-09-01T14:07:59.413 Attaching package: 'rjson'
2017-09-01T14:07:59.429 The following objects are masked from 'package:jsonlite':

    fromJSON, toJSON
2017-09-01T14:07:59.976 Error: Please install xml2 package
2017-09-01T14:07:59.976 In addition: Warning message:
In strptime(x, fmt, tz = "GMT") : unable to identify current timezone 'C':
please set environment variable 'TZ'
2017-09-01T14:07:59.976 Execution halted
2017-09-01T14:08:00.028 Function completed (Success, Id=c031b7fc-1047-442e-8589-8cc6e7a96b48, Duration=7637ms)
```

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Comment: There is written: "Please install xml2 package".. have you checked this?

Comment: @Oswald: I tried adding it to the script both of these options as the first line on the `script.r` file. `install.packages("xml2", repos = "http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/")` and `install.packages("xml2")` but ended with the same errors. Is there a way to invoke this package download from the Azure diagnostic console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also followed this example and it worked fine on my side.

[image]

It seems that you haven't run the following command in step 5 in [the doc](https://github.com/thdeltei/azure-function-r#installing-the-r-extension) you provided.

```
unzip -n D:\home\SiteExtensions\R-3.3.3x64\R-3.3.3.zip -d D:\home
```

Comment: OK, I deleted all my containers and function app and started from scratch. Now its working. Looks like something went wrong during adding the extension.